# Cucumber example inputs are received incorrectly

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

**Cucumber Version:** 11.0

Facing a weird issue that first example input parameters are being taken along with other column values.

```
**Feature:** Some feature

  @foo
  **Scenario Outline:** Testing.
    Given Send Request and Validate response <language> <location> <address>
    **Examples:**
      | language | location | address |
      | test     | tt       | foo     |
      | test pp  | mm       | boo     |
      
      
  @Given("^Given Send Request and Validate response (.*) (.*) (.*)$")
  public void Send_Request_and_Validate_response(String language, String location, String address) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("The language is " + language);
        System.out.println("The location is " + location);
```

**Expected:-**

```
The language is test 
The location is tt

The language is test pp
The location is mm
```

**Actual:-**

```
The language is test tt
The location is foo

The language is test pp
The location is mm
```

I am not sure why the first parameter 'language' in first inputs alone print 'tt' which is given under location. I see no such issue from second input. Any help?

Comment: Pls check if there are any special hidden characters between the demarcation line (i.e. | ) between "test" and "tt"

Comment: Which Cucumber version / dependency are you using exactly? There is no version 11 (yet)

Comment: This works fine after replacing the input line with other input. Special hidden characters could have been the reason. Thanks @JeromeJosephraj and Marit

Comment: @Learner - Would you pls accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check if there are any special hidden characters between the demarcation line (i.e. | ) between "test" and "tt"

[image]